# Pointer to Global Variable as Class Member

Tags: c++

I have a class `Foo`, which I want to be able to write to a global array, `Bar`.

In `Global.h`

```cpp
extern float Bar[256];
```

In `Foo.h`

```cpp
class Foo {
   public:
      Foo(float array[])
      void write(float toWrite);

   private:
      char ptr;
}
```

In `Foo.cpp`

```cpp
Foo::write(float toWrite){
   array[ptr] = toWrite;
   ptr++;
}
```

In `main.cpp`:

```
#include "Global.h"
#include "Foo.h"

Foo foo(Bar);

main(){
  foo.toWrite(100);
}
```

Is this the correct way to pass a pointer to the global array to the new object? I don't want to create a local copy.

Comment: Since the variable is global, it's visible from everywhere. There are many ways to pass it, the idea *above all* is to avoid having a global variable.

Comment: The idea is ok, but you need to store `float *array` in a member, which you're not currently doing, and `char ptr` isn't a pointer but an index, and is anyway too small to index the whole array if `char` is signed.

Comment: There are no pointers in this question (except in the ctor arg, which is unused). What "new object"? Sorry, I don't get it. Please present a real [mcve].

Comment: Would storing `float *array` as a member not create a local copy?

Comment: No it won't, `float*` stores an address - not more, not less.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid an XY problem when answering this question. Why do you want to use a global variable? If it's because you want a single instance of Bar across all instances of your class Foo, then you can do this using a static member variable without the need for an ugly global variable. If you want each instance of Foo to map it's Bar array onto a different block of memory then that's a different question.

You also need to initialise the value of your index, here is some example code.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo();
    void write(float toWrite);

    static float Bar[256];

  private:
    unsigned char index;
};

float Foo::Bar[256] = {0,0,0,0,0};

Foo::Foo(){
  index = 0;
}

void Foo::write(float toWrite){
  Foo::Bar[index++] = toWrite;
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo1, foo2;

    foo1.write(100);
    foo1.write(100);
    foo2.write(200);

    std::cout << Foo::Bar[0] << ", " << Foo::Bar[1] << ", " << Foo::Bar[2] << ", " << Foo::Bar[3] << "\n";
}
```

Will print out

```
200, 100, 0, 0
```